# Can Sway magnify the application window?

Tags: sway

One problem I have when running applications under Wayland Sway is that sometimes the application fonts (used in menus, for example) are too small. This is especially the case if I am using a high resolution monitor.

Is there any way to magnify the window in Sway so that everything gets bigger, including the fonts?

Comment: Possibly related open issue [here](https://github.com/swaywm/sway/issues/2781).